# How to construct .NET connection string to Oracle without TNS?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, sharepoint-2010, toad

I have a Sharepoint 2010 .NET 3.5 system running on my local Windows 7 machine with IIS. I have been unable to connect to our corporate Oracle database via Oracle.DataAccess.dll. The error message I get in my .NET webapp (sharepoint) is "ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified".

Here's the good news:

- I can connect to this DB fine with TOAD, from my same PC.
- Our TEST server can connect fine to the DB through sharepoint/.net and everything.

So it feels like I'm very close and just need to tweak something. A bunch of articles I read say to cut out the TNS/ora file and go straight from .net to the DB by constructing a .net connection string thusly:

connString="user id=usridname;password=yourpassword;data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=hostnamehere)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicenamehere)));"

I would love to use this approach. I have the username and password, but I don't know how to discover the other parts. It's probably a simple thing to discover the hostname, port, and servicename by examining my TOAD connection, or by peeking in some file on the TEST server that works. But I have no idea where to look, either in toad, or on the test server where it works. I have full remote desktop admin access to the test server, so I can look at anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to locate your `tnsnames.ora` file and check the entries.

Run `tnsping` from the command line of the server you are running with the name of the connection you connect to with toad.

```
> tnsping haki

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on 16-JUN-2013 14:14:10

Copyright (c) 1997, 2006, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_3\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = *****)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = haki))) 
OK (0 msec)
```

Look for a file called `tnsadmin.ora` under the network parameter directory. as you can see, in my case it's `C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_3\network\admin\`.

If this dosent work or you located the file but the entry wasn't there try running `netca` and create an entry using the wizard.

sometimes people install more then one client software and there a whole mess with the `PATH`.

Comment: The best solution was to do a tnsping and then grab the values to construct the connection string with: connString="user id=usridname;password=yourpassword;data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=hostnamehere)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicenamehere)));"